# Invalid xml character in NetworkStream

Tags: c#, xml, tcpclient, networkstream

I am using `TcpClient` to request data from a remote server in a C# forms application.  I have a problem when I receive data in XML format, as there is a control character (%) in front of the XML root.  I know this because I can see it when I use a console application to receive the data.

In the forms application, I have tried to receive the data through `NetworkStream`, and then read the byte array and convert it to a string before parsing it.  Maybe this is the wrong approach - please correct me if so!

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formattedRequest);
ns.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

byte[] serverResponse = new byte[1024];
serverResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\n");
ns.Write(serverResponse, 0, serverResponse.Length);

byte[] newMsg = new byte[1024];
myStream.serverBytes = ns.Read(newMsg, 0, newMsg.Length);

string invalidString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newMsg, 0, myStream.serverBytes);
string cleanString = invalidString.Remove(0, 1);
//Attempt at removing the invalid % character before XML root.

var fullItem = XDocument.Parse(quoteString);
string itemA = quote.Descendants("QUOTE").Select(x => x.Attribute("itemA").Value).FirstOrDefault();
string askString = quote.Descendants("QUOTE").Select(x => x.Attribute("itemB").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

At the line `var quote = XDocument.Parse(quoteString)`, this error occurs:

`XmlException: hexadecimal value 0x01 is an invalid character.  Line 1, position 1.`

Apparently, there is a good reason for this because the % in front of the XML root is an invalid XML character and so will not load it (see http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/ ).  But the solution in this article seems very involved for such a (seemingly) small problem.

How can I get the data from the stream in XML format so that I can read itemA and itemB, without the XMLException being thrown because of the control character before the XML root?

Comment: Are you sure you want ASCII encoding? ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. Any character with a code above 127 will be converted to a question mark. If the data you're getting uses Windows-1252 code page or UTF-8, for example, converting with the ASCII encoding is going to destroy your data.

Comment: ASCII works for all the other server responses, so on that basis it should surely be no different here.  I've just tried UTF-8 and it throws the same error at the same line.